# Azure Queue: Unable to read cloud queue messages. AsString and AsBytes properties are throwing System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-queues

Ok, I have a class intended to manage Azure cloud queue messages, the **insertions** are working fine:

```
    public async void Insert(string message)
    {
        await Queue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(message));
    }
```

Note that this `Queue` is a `CloudQueue` instance.

[image: This is the message inserted in the storage using the above method]

*This is the message inserted in the storage using the above method*

But, while trying to **Get** or **Peek** messages, a weird behavior is happening and I can't read anything of the content:

[image: The content of the message is throwing an exception and is being returned as null]

*The content of the message is throwing an exception and is being returned as null.*

[image: This is the messageCount value]

*This is the `messageCount` value.*

Here's textually, the method used to retrieve the messages:

```
    public async Task<List<string>> GetMessages()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        await Queue.FetchAttributesAsync();
        int messageCount = Queue.ApproximateMessageCount ?? 0;

        if (messageCount == 0) return list;

        foreach (var msg in await Queue.GetMessagesAsync(messageCount))
        {
            
             list.Add(msg.AsString);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

**EDIT:** I checked as pointed in the approved answer and figured out that I was using a deprecated package that seems to work no longer.
[image: Deprecated package]
*This library has been split in multiple parts and is deprecated.*

I had to use a most recent API and change my code, it's actually easier to use but a certain rework was needed. It's now working, and the way to use the queue in this new version (**.NET v12**) is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues?tabs=dotnet#create-a-queue).

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the complete stack trace. Also what's the value for `messageCount`?

Comment: OK. Actually I could not access the stack trace using that popup. Also, the `messageCount` is returning `1`. I will see if I can get the stack and then put both of them in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Just put your `foreach` block inside a `try/catch` block and you should be able to see the stack trace.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't catch. I think it's being handled internally.

Comment: The latest releases can be found here: https://aka.ms/azsdk/releases - All of the new packages start with "Azure.", not "Microsoft."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's related to wrong (legacy) Nuget Package. I've faced a problem like this recently and it was solved when I've upgraded to the following Packages:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common -Version 11.1.7
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue -Version 11.1.7
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common/

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out and let you know if is this the problem.

Comment: PS: There's a high chance you'll need to change the app that is also sending messages to the queue

Comment: The latest releases can be found here: https://aka.ms/azsdk/releases - All of the new packages start with "Azure.", not "Microsoft."

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. You should update all your packages to their latest versions and it will work fine.